# Editar perguntas com erros "feios" de português?

Tags: debate, edição

Não sei se alguém já se deparou quando iria editar alguma pergunta e viu alguns erros bem "feios", dizendo de uma forma mais polida. Eu cheguei a editar mas não salvei pois talvez o autor poderia se ofender ou algo do tipo.

Não era nem erro de concordância ou algo do tipo. Era algo assim:

> *precizo* *faser* um aplicativo

ou

> preciso *deserealizar* um objeto

O que acham? Vocês corrigem?

Comment: O pior são os de concordância. Grafia incorreta até dá pra entender. Mas em geral, eu edito sim.

Comment: Os de concordância chegam mudar o sentido. Tenho vontade de dar um chute de tão ofendido que eu me sinto :D :D :D

Comment: Algumas vezes eu mesmo chego a cometer esses tipos de erros "feios", eu sempre pesquiso a palavra no dicionário para checar se ela esta correta quando eu estou perguntando ou respondendo. Mais da para identificar alguma dificuldade da parte do usuário em relação a escrita, mas muitas vezes tem usuários que não ligam para o português e escreve de qualquer jeito e nem pensam em corrigir. Então eu digo: edite os posts com esses erros, ninguém tem que se ofender com isso, se o usuário se sentir ofendido porque teve o post editado é exagero *overreact*.

Comment: @Maniero flag => texto ofensivo à língua portuguesa

Comment: @gato eu tb, por isso estou tirando sarro de mim mesmo, pra dar tempo de fazer tudo eu faço rápido demais, inclusive para não perder o fio da meada, sem entrar em mais detalhes, é normal errar e é bom consertar, cada um com seus defeitos e suas qualidades.

Comment: Um erro de português é tão problemático quanto um erro de programação. Se você não consegue se expressar direito, é provável que não consiga elaborar sobre um problema (e vice-versa).

Comment: @Renan ainda bem que disse que é provável :) Eu tenho comportamento muito diferente quando estou fazendo algo correndo e quando eu paro e penso sobre, e obviamente que sabendo disso e querendo fazer bem feito, só continuo errando porque sou inepto a fazer melhor por motivos que não vem ao caso :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Corrigimos sim, é importante corrigir erros ortográficos, gramáticas e até de clareza. Só tome o cuidado para não mudar o sentido do que está escrito.

Erros são ofensas para a língua portuguesa. Mas não preciso ficar só no abstrato, pessoas também podem se ofender.

Vivemos dias em que todo mundo se ofende com alguma coisa. Se for considerar assim tem quem se ofenda com textos escritos errados. Como resolvemos quando cada ação é ofensa para um grupo de pessoas e a ação que não é ofensa para aquele grupo é para outro?

Por isso que eu acho que tem que tomar cuidado com esse negócio das pessoas se sentirem ofendidas. O que é muito diferente de ofender alguém. A pessoa escolher se sentir ofendida é diferente de quem fez a suposta ofensa ter tido a intenção de ofender, ou, mesmo com intenção ter feito algo que seja considerado universalmente uma ofensa.

Dissabor não é ofensa.

Então uma edição para arrumar o texto é um favor que fazemos para todos, e de certa forma principalmente para o autor do erro não passar vergonha. O mecanismo está aí para isto. É desejável que a edição seja feita.

Não é obrigatório, e tem caso que acho que pode deixar de lado mesmo. Costuma ser mais interessante quando a pessoa melhora outras coisas junto, principalmente quando a pessoa ganha os 2 pontos pela edição, já que pode caracterizar que a pessoas está editando só por causa disto, e muita gente não aceita bem esse caça pontos.

Cuidado, porque tem palavras que são corretas em outros países e você não sabe disto, ou outras que são neologismos geralmente aceitos.

Comment: maravilha Maniero, obrigado pela resposta.