# A gramática deve ser levada em conta para se editar uma pergunta?

Tags: debate

Erros gramaticais devem ser levados em consideração para se editar uma pergunta, mesmo que não afetem diretamente a clareza da questão?

Comment: [Creio que sim.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6724/revisions)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Editar perguntas com erros "feios" de português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6618/editar-perguntas-com-erros-feios-de-portugu%c3%aas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Sim

Editar perguntas e respostas para corrigir erros gramaticais, de concordância verbal e nominal, de acentuação, de pontuação e de formatação é algo muito bem-vindo e bem visto aqui no SOpt.

Entretanto, todas as edições devem respeitar algumas regrinhas básicas:

- Não edite uma pergunta ou resposta com mudanças que não melhoram nada ([exemplo 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/138818), [exemplo 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/134432)).
- Não coloque palavras na boca de outra pessoa. Não altere a redação da pergunta ou resposta inserindo coisas que mudem de forma significativa o sentido do que foi perguntado ou respondido ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/145877)).
- Não tente conversar com o autor da pergunta ou resposta por meio de edições, use comentários ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/145674)).
- Não transforme a pergunta ou resposta em algo completamente diferente. Antes de submeter uma edição veja se está editando a coisa certa ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/144758)).
- Em caso de dúvidas, o melhor é deixar um comentário.

Revisão textual da estrutura da redação e esclarecimentos também são válidas, mas aqui é preciso um pouco mais de cuidado e experiência:

- Incorporar na pergunta comentários esclarecedores que o autor fizer é bom.
- Incorporar o conteúdo de respostas que o autor da pergunta posta e que deveriam ser edições na pergunta é bom.
- Em alguns casos raros, incorporar o conteúdo de comentários em respostas também é válido.
- Remover trechos de texto que sejam apenas "encheção de linguiça" ou que não tenham a ver com o conteúdo da pergunta ou resposta também é bom. Entretanto, é preciso um tanto de prudência, cuidado e reflexão crítica aqui para evitar de remover coisas demais. Em casos duvidosos, prefira deixar um comentário ou deixar como está.
- [Tome cuidado ao revisar formatação.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132)
- [Tome cuidado ao revisar código, mesmo que seja indentação.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/132)

Se a sua edição respeita as regras acima, mesmo que seja uma edição de erro gramatical, ela provavelmente é bem-vinda e será aprovada.

Comment: "_Remover trechos de texto que sejam "encheção de linguiça" ou que não tenham a ver com o conteúdo da pergunta ou resposta também é bom._".... isso é perigoso, pq pode haver interpretação do editor, mudando o sentido da pergunta. Acho mais recomendável que o próprio AP faça alterações na redação mediante sugestões nos comentários.

Comment: @dvd Editado. Está melhor?

Comment: Ficou mt bom! Bem mais explicativo nesse ponto.

Comment: O problema é a pessoa fazer uma alteraçãozinha boba pra ganhar 2 pontos, mas a melhoria realmente é bem vinda.