# Perguntas boas a nível de programação mas repletas de erros de português devem ser consideradas de "má qualidade"?

Tags: debate, qualidade

Considerando uma pergunta boa a nível de programação, com explicações claras e diretas do problema, porém repleta de erros ortográficos e gramaticais graves, merecem ser avaliadas como de "má qualidade" e digna de um *downvote*?

> Encontrei alguns tópicos aqui em relação ao assunto, como este abaixo:
>
> [Editar perguntas com erros "feios" de português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6618/8063)
>
> Porém a minha abordagem vai um pouco mais além, em relação a votar em
>   tais perguntas.

Bem sei que o propósito do SOPT não é avaliar o nível de português de quem pergunta ou responde, mas primordialmente a clareza, objetividade e inerência do conteúdo com o escopo e propósito do site. Mas por outro lado, acredito que a qualidade gramatical das postagens também tem a sua parcela numa avaliação geral (ou não?).

Claro que ninguém precisa ser um professor Pasquale ao formular as suas perguntas, mas eu tenho a impressão de que textos com erros tão feios tornam o site.... feio também, e de alguma forma prejudicam a sua qualidade. É perfeitamente aceitável, ao meu ver, um erro ou outro (às vezes o autor nem notou) mas vejo muitas (mas muitas mesmo) postagens onde são ignorados acentuações, pontuações (que por vezes prejudicam o entendimento) e diversos outros erros de escrita, embora a pergunta seja até boa a nível de programação e escopo.

Obviamente podemos utilizar o editor para corrigir tais erros, tornando a pergunta menos feia, por assim dizer, mas gostaria de saber, de forma mais apurada, qual é o critério a ser adotado em relação a isso: devemos votar negativo em perguntas até boas pelo seu teor, mas com um português muito ruim? Ou devemos considerar exclusivamente o seu teor como sendo o suficiente para avaliar a pergunta, não levando em conta o excesso de erros graves de português? Ou ainda, em casos como esses, não fazer nenhuma avaliação (abster-se de votar)?

Enfim, o que acham disso e, além das indagações acima, qual a postura oficial da comunidade em relação a isso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De forma geral não são consideras ruins. Claro estamos falando de ortografia e gramática ou com vícios de linguagem ("a nivel de" é errado :) por isso eu digo que quase ninguém usa português certo, começando por mim), mas está tudo claro, e compreensível.

Pessoalmente, ou seja, não como moderador, considero que algo cheio de erros denigre a imagem do autor, não porque ela é ignorante, mas porque ele é relaxada. Erros de digitação, desconhecimento de regras malucas a nossa língua, descuido eventual pela pressa me parece algo normal. O problema é a pessoa não ter nenhum preocupação em fazer certo ou errar em coisas muito básicas. De fato não merce negativo por causa disto isoladamente. É importante para a pessoa ser um profissional completo e que mostre um mínimo de capricho, de comprometimento com o que está fazendo ali. E por que não dizer um pouco de respeito com as outras pessoas, principalmente aquela que irá responder a pergunta.

Claro que vale também para respostas, mas já notou como é muito mais raro acontecer o mesmo em respostas? Não me parece ser coincidência, não é?

De fato não estamos aqui para criticar o português da pessoa, mas tudo tem limite. E o fato de não estarmos aqui primordialmente para ensinar português, o ideal é ensinarmos passivamente editando o problema. Infelizmente a atitude geral (e a ferramenta também ajuda) é de ignorar o que foi feito, temos usuários recorrentes que continuam fazendo os mesmo erros que corrigiram em postagens dela (ela nem vê o que acontecem nas postagens dos outros).

Pra tudo existe exceção. A multitude de erros pode em algum caso disparar o gatilho da má qualidade, da falta de esforço e quem sabe afete a clareza. Por isso não digo que nunca mereça um negativo, e claro que não possa ser fechada por falta de clareza. Mas precisa ser algo bem exagerado. E o melhor é consertar o problema. Na maioria dos casos é fácil consertar.

Eu cansei de consertar tudo como fazia no começo, hoje faço mais no que eu respondo. Mas mexo mais em *tags*. Este é um problema maior e não vejo o pessoa melhorando muito. Se tiver que escolher (e não precisa) prefiro mexer na *tag* do que consertar o português.

Não acho que exista um critério claro, e considero que acaba sendo um pouco pessoal o que fazer. Lembrando que não podemos obrigar ninguém arrumar um problema. É chato ver a pessoa consertar um erro e não consertar outros. Ou introduzir novos.

Não posso dizer que todo mundo deva fazer o mesmo, mas se tiver muito erro e eu não achar que vale a pena melhorar, mesmo que a pergunta seja fantástica não receberá meu positivo. Ainda que se ela for tão fantástica assim provavelmente eu melhorarei.

Mas quer outra opinião baseada na minha observação. Estamos falando de casos bem raros. A imensa maioria dos casos que tem esses problemas todos não tem o conteúdo bom. Entender o problema, ser claro, conseguir colocar tudo de forma completa, saber um mínimo de método científico (o básico mesmo, aquilo que todo mundo com ensino fundamental deveria saber para viver em sociedade de forma produtiva), são coisas muito mais difíceis de acertar do que ortografia e gramática. Uma coisa que a pessoa não percebe é que este tipo de atitude atrofia o cérebro. Ele acostuma fazer ruim em tudo na vida. Pode existir alguém, mas geralmente as pessoas não possuem um botão de liga e desliga o relaxo. Se você treinar andar com as mãos você ficará bom nisso, e aos poucos perderá a habilidade de andar com as pernas.

Eu queria que pudéssemos fazer mais por essas pessoas, mas é contraproducente por uma série de razões.

Postura oficial da comunidade não posso dizer, não é algo que seja regra, algumas pessoas podem discordar de mim.

E não sei se eu criticaria alguém negativar tal aberração :)

Comment: Creio que seja isso mesmo. Obg. Também acho que as tags sejam mais importantes. Hoje mesmo achei 11 perguntas com a tag [javacript] (sem o "s"). Tive que entrar em cada uma e remover e adicionar a correta [javascript].

Answer (score 4):

Excelente abordagem do @Maniero sobre o assunto. Eu acreditei mesmo que a comunidade em si não possua um critério "oficial" sobre o assunto, que é mais algo de critério pessoal, mas eu resolvi perguntar pra definir um "norte" mais apurado.

Realmente é bem raro uma pergunta muito boa em termos de conteúdo de programação mas redigida de uma bem lamentável a nível de um português razoável. Embora sejam raros os casos, vez em quando aparecem uns, e uma dessas que vi esses dias me inspirou a levantar a questão.

Eu vinha adotando o critério de não votar em perguntas com péssimo português, mesmo analisando num contexto geral que a pergunta tem até um conteúdo bom quando você vai lendo e fazendo em mente as inúmeras correções gramaticais. Mas confesso que isso me deixa meio desanimado em dar algum tipo de voto -- aliás, a vontade que dá é dar logo um downvote, mas eu me seguro porque faço uma média: conteúdo por trás da pergunta = 10, a forma que foi feita (o português escrito) = 0; logo, média = 5, e deixo de votar, seja positivamente ou negativamente (exceto se depois eu voltar lá e estiver tudo corrigido, aí sim tendo a prestigiar a pergunta votando up).

No entanto, também tem a parte de melhorar a pergunta fazendo as devidas correções. Se por um lado isso é até interessante, afim de melhorar a qualidade da pergunta, por outro o autor nunca vai se esforçar em aprender a escrever pelo menos um português razoável. Confesso que acho mais produtivo fazer um comentário na pergunta instruindo o autor a melhorar a sua redação, alertando-o que todos os erros de português cometidos prejudicam o entendimento da pergunta. Numa dessas perguntas vi um usuário experiente fazendo isso, e achei bastante interessante.

Realmente creio que em tudo que formos fazer devemos fazer o melhor e da forma certa, ou pelo menos se esforçar para isso. Vejo muito desleixo nessa área por parte da maioria dos usuários, que são novos e relativamente novos. Vejo que muitos deles querem aprender a programar (os que realmente querem, que são poucos) mas dá impressão que eles não se importam com outras coisas importantes na vida, como saber escrever bem.

Eu particularmente me esforço bastante. A nossa língua é complicada, mas eu não gosto de fazer as coisas de qualquer jeito, principalmente escrever. Eu não domino todas as regras da língua, e muitas vezes dou meus deslizes, mas eu me esforço bastante pra aprender. Tenho um certo conhecimento da língua inglesa e não me lembro de ter visto no SOen erros ortográficos, ao contrário do que ocorre no SOpt, que é a coisa mais comum.

Enfim, vou seguir o que o @Maniero abordou. Também acho que não seja caso de downvote, mas irei, em casos esdrúxulos, emitir um comentário instruindo o autor a melhorar o português afim de melhorar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a negativação ou abstenção do voto seja algo relevante caso os erros sejam tão grosseiros ao ponto de dificultar ou tornar dúbia a pergunta/resposta, exigindo a reformulação da mesma.

O ideal seria que o escritos fizesse um esforço para melhor compreensão de todos, visto a proposta de postagens perpetuas do SOPT.

Comment: Não acho que a negativação seja necessária. Se é boa no nível de programação como exemplificado acho que vale um comentário pra pessoa não ser tão relaxada da próxima e podemos ajudar a melhorar caso tenha muito erro de gramática. Eu mesmo costumo fazer isso mesmo meu português não sendo dos melhores.